# Current price of steam items into excel

Tags: excel, steam

I found some answers about this talking about some API, but I dont understand what that is. Is there a way to have a cell in excel with the current price of an item in the steam market and having that price update?

Please excuse my lack of knowledge:3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, your question isn't really a solid question and what a i mean with that is you talk very briefly about your problem but heck lets go
So first of all i would suggest you learning python if you haven't already learned it.
Then look for some tutorial of "how to use a web api" and research the requests library for python.
All done?
Good, now steam has some kind of api, which i never looked into really but here:
`https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested)`

This gives you some stats about the weapon in this case its the AK Elite Build Field-Tested,
The ouput will have just some data but enough, there will be the lowest price available for you.
(lowest steam market offering for the item you specified in the "url".

Comment: oh yeah and you have to change the "appid" to the game the item belongs to, this is a csgo skin so csgo's appid on steam is 730 (as written in the url).